# Logical error in retrieving the string from the map-C++

Tags: c++

I could able to run the program but nothing gets displayed..
If I replace `.find("1")` I'm getting compiler error as const char cannot be changed to const int.
If I replace with `.find('1')` then I'm getting the output as "string is not in the map".
I need to retrieve the string with the key value 1. How should I modify my program to get the desired result.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef map<int,string> EventTypeMap;
    EventTypeMap EventType;

    EventType[1]="beata"; 
    EventType[2]="jane"; 
    EventType[3]="declan"; 

    if(EventType.find(1)==EventType.end()) 
    {     
        cout<<"string is not in the map!"<<endl; 
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your problem to be honest. Your key-type is `int`, so in `find()` method you should give this exact `int` as the key. Code given in your question is OK.

If nothing gets displayed *in this exact code you have posted*, it is because you do have key `(int)1` in your map. To display value assigned to this key, you could write:

```
cout << EventType.find(1)->second << endl;
```

---

**Edit** Still don't know what your problem is and if it is really a problem. Here is code that must work -- tested on GCC and Visual C++ 2008:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef map<int, string> EventTypeMap;
    EventTypeMap EventType;

    EventType[1] = "beata"; 
    EventType[2] = "jane"; 
    EventType[3] = "declan"; 

    int idx = 1;
    if (EventType.find(idx) == EventType.end()) 
        cout << "string is not in the map!" << endl; 
    else
        cout << EventType.find(idx)->second << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried with what you told me and got Debug Assertion failed! error.

Comment: @Beata What compiler do you use? I've tried it with GCC 4.5 and everything is just fine. By the `#include "stdafx.h"` I suppose it is Visual C++, but what version?

Comment: I dont know how to see the version of the compiler i'm using...got this info Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 Installed Edition: VC Express Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 91909-152-0000052-60784 Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the string first, or key your collection by characters

```
typedef map<int,string> EventTypeMap;
EventTypeMap EventType;

EventType[1]="beata"; 
EventType[2]="jane"; 
EventType[3]="declan"; 

if(EventType.find(atoi("1"))==EventType.end())
```

or

```
typedef map<char,string> EventTypeMap;
EventTypeMap EventType;

EventType['1']="beata"; 
EventType['2']="jane"; 
EventType['3']="declan"; 

if(EventType.find('1')==EventType.end())
```

Comment: I tried in both the forms but i'm not getting the output.when tried with the 1st one i'm getting a compiler error that atoi cannot convert char from const char*.when tried with the 2nd one no compiler error and no output.